# How to add "allowDiskUse" in @Aggregation annotation in repository in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, aggregation, mongorepository

I have an aggregation written in a `MyRepository.kt` file which is being called from `MongoDataRetriever.kt` file in the backend.

`MyRepository.kt` file:

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Aggregation
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository

  @Aggregation(pipeline = [
    "{ \$match: { 'objName' : { \$exists: true } } }",
    "{ \$sort: { 'addedDate': -1 } }"
  ])
  fun getLatestObjectsWithLatestData(): List<MyDocument>
```

and `MongoDataRetriever.kt` file:

```
  override fun getLatestObjects(): List<MyObj> {
    return myRepository.getLatestObjectsWithLatestData().map { it.toMyObj() }
  }
```

The above `aggregation` is failing with error:

`message: "Command failed with error 16819 (Location16819): 'Sort exceeded memory limit of 104857600 bytes, but did not opt in to external sorting. Aborting operation. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in.' on serv...`

So, It seems adding `allowDiskUse = true` or something like that is the possible fix, but how to add that in the above annotation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add @Meta(allowDiskUse = true) annotation to your method.

```
@Aggregation(pipeline = [
"{ \$match: { 'objName' : { \$exists: true } } }",
"{ \$sort: { 'addedDate': -1 } }"
])
@Meta(allowDiskUse = true)
fun getLatestObjectsWithLatestData(): List<MyDocument>
```